# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in [location] on line 7

Tags: php, html, mysql

I keep getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in D:\server\WT-NMP\WWW\myproj1\insert.php on line 7

With this code:

```
<?php
$uname = $_REQUEST['uname'];
$msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','chatbox');

mysqli_query($con"INSERT INTO logs (`username` , `msg`) VALUES ('$uname','$msg')");

$result1 = mysqli_query($con"SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");

while($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
        echo "<span class='uname'>" . $extract['username'] . "</span>: <span class='msg'>" . $extract['msg'] . "</span><br>";
    }




?>
```

Comment: So is line 7 the line that starts with `mysqli_query($con"INSERT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con"SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");
```

to this:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");
```

Same thing for the Insert.

Also that mysqli_fetch_array should be mysqli_fetch_assoc.

And while we're at it, you have a sql injection problem with insert. You should be using a prepared statement and bind those params. Just sticking user supplied data into your SQL is never a good idea.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out for ages!

Comment: You have like 5 bugs in that code, keep plugging those holes.

Comment: @LightningXD can you mark my answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

First, you are missing a comma in your SQL statements
Change this:

```
mysqli_query($con"INSERT INTO logs (`username` , `msg`) VALUES ('$uname','$msg')");
```

by this:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO logs (`username` , `msg`) VALUES ('$uname','$msg')");
```

And change this:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con"SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");
```

By this:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");
```

You should also use queries with parameter because at the moment your insert is open to SQL injection.

Comment: Great minds think alike.